# How to properly update references while installing a Dnn package

Tags: msbuild, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have been using Chris Hammond's template to create my dnn modules.

Recently I add a Class library project and was able to create an installer that looks like:

[image]

..still, the installer doesn't copy (or update) the reference to the bin folder in the server when we use it.
Could you please tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer where I explain how to add dependent dlls to your build script such that they are included and deployed with your extension package.

[How to Properly Reference Assemblies in DNN Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797464/how-to-properly-reference-assemblies-in-dnn-manifest/57811281#57811281)

Comment: I use your answer before and that's the way I'm having the extra dll in the install zip. Still, it doesn't install(copy) it (the extra dll) on the server.

Comment: If you look at the linked question, the user included his entire .DNN manifest file with the <component type="Assembly"> section.  Notice he includes an entry for each dependent .dll as well as the module assembly .dll in that section.  That may be what you are missing to install the assemblies from the zip package.